# Postgresql generate date series (performance)

Tags: sql, postgresql, dateinterval, generate-series

Using postgresql version > 10, I have come to an issue when generating date series using the built-in `generate_series` function. In essence, it does not accord for the `day of the month` correctly.

I have many different frequencies (provided by the user) that need to be calculated between a given start and end date. The start date can be any date and thus any day of the month. This generates issues when having frequencies such as `monthly` combined with a start date of `2018-01-31` or `2018-01-30` as shown in the output below.

I created a solution and wanted to post this here for others to use as I could not find any other solution.

However, after some tests I have seen that my solution has a different  performance compared to the built-in `generate_series` when used on (absurdly) large date ranges. Does anyone have an insight as to how this can be improved?

**TL;DR**: if possible avoid loops as they are a performance hit, scroll to bottom for improved implementation.

### Built-in Output

```
select generate_series(date '2018-01-31', 
                       date '2018-05-31', 
                       interval '1 month')::date
as frequency;
```

generates:

```
 frequency
------------
 2018-01-31
 2018-02-28
 2018-03-28
 2018-04-28
 2018-05-28
```

As can be seen from the output, the day of the month is not respected and truncated to the minimum day encountered along the way, in this case: `28 due to the month of februari`.

### Expected Output

As a result of this issue I created a custom function:

```
create or replace function generate_date_series(
  starts_on date, 
  ends_on date, 
  frequency interval)
returns setof date as $$
declare
  interval_on date := starts_on;
  count int := 1;
begin
  while interval_on <= ends_on loop
    return next interval_on;
    interval_on := starts_on + (count * frequency);
    count := count + 1;
  end loop;
  return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;

select generate_date_series(date '2018-01-31', 
                            date '2018-05-31', 
                            interval '1 month')
as frequency;
```

generates:

```
 frequency
------------
 2018-01-31
 2018-02-28
 2018-03-31
 2018-04-30
 2018-05-31
```

### Performance comparison

No matter what date range is provided, the built-in `generate_series` has a performance of **2ms on average** for:

```
select generate_series(date '1900-01-01', 
                       date '10000-5-31', 
                       interval '1 month')::date 
as frequency;
```

while the custom function `generate_date_series` has a performance of **120ms on average** for:

```
select generate_date_series(date '1900-01-01', 
                            date '10000-5-31', 
                            interval '1 month')::date 
as frequency;
```

### Question

In reality, such ranges will never occur and thus it is a non-issue. For most queries the custom `generate_date_series` will attain the same performance. Although, I do wonder what causes the difference.

Is there a reason why the built-in function is able to attain a constant performance of **2ms on average** no matter what range is provided?

Is there a better way to implement `generate_date_series` that performs as well as the built-in `generate_series`?

### Improved implementation without loops

(derived from the answer of @eurotrash)

```
create or replace function generate_date_series(
  starts_on date, 
  ends_on date, 
  frequency interval)
returns setof date as $$
select (starts_on + (frequency * count))::date
from (
  select (row_number() over ()) - 1 as count
  from generate_series(starts_on, ends_on, frequency)
) series
$$ language sql immutable;
```

with the improved implementation, the `generate_date_series` function has a performance of **45ms on average** for:

```
select generate_date_series(date '1900-01-01', 
                            date '10000-5-31', 
                            interval '1 month')::date 
as frequency;
```

The implementation provided by @eurotrash gives me **80ms on average**, which I assume is due to calling the `generate_series` function twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why your function is slow: you use variables and (more importantly) a loop. Loops are slow. Variables also mean reads from and writes to those variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_date_series_2(starts_on DATE, ends_on DATE, frequency INTERVAL)
        RETURNS SETOF DATE AS
$BODY$
        SELECT (starts_on + (frequency * g))::DATE
        FROM generate_series(0, (SELECT COUNT(*)::INTEGER - 1 FROM generate_series(starts_on, ends_on, frequency))) g;
$BODY$
        LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

The concept is basically the same as your plpgsql function but via a single query instead of a loop. The only problem is deciding how many iterations are needed (i.e. the second parameter to generate_series). Sadly I couldn't think of a better way to get the number of intervals required other than calling generate_series for the dates and using the count of that. Of course if you know your intervals will only ever be certain values then it may be possible to optimise; however this version handles any interval values.

On my system it's about 50% slower than a pure generate_series, and about 400% faster than your plpgsql version.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I like your implementation as it keeps my solution to get the correct dates without any trickery and it removes the loop completely. However, the double call to `generate_series` did bother me, so I revised your implementation to remove one call. I extended my question to include this implementation.

Comment: @chvndb Nice, I like your new implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**REVISED SOLUTION**

This gives me 97,212 rows in under 7 seconds (approx 0.7ms per row) and also supports `leap-years` where February have 29 days:

```
SELECT      t.day_of_month
FROM        (
                SELECT  ds.day_of_month
                        , date_part('day', ds.day_of_month) AS day
                        , date_part('day', ((day_of_month - date_part('day', ds.day_of_month)::INT + 1) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS eom
                FROM    (
                            SELECT generate_series( date '1900-01-01', 
                                                    date '10000-12-31', 
                                                    INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE as day_of_month
                        ) AS ds
            ) AS t
            --> REMEMBER to change the day at both places below (eg. 31)
WHERE       t.day = 31 OR (t.day = t.eom AND t.day < 31)
```

**Resulting output:**
Please ensure you change the day on **BOTH** the RED numbers.
[image: Performance Output]

The output data:

[image: Data Output]

Comment: This does not generate the expected output. The problem with this is that it only works for the end of the month, but what if the interval starts on the 30th.

Comment: Revised the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may use  `date_trunc` and add a month to the output of`generate_series`, the performance should be almost similar.

```
SELECT 
  (date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day') ::DATE AS frequency 
FROM 
  generate_series(
    DATE '2018-01-31', DATE '2018-05-31', 
    interval '1 MONTH'
  ) AS dt
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=86fa64a4df1e37e709c54a752ca41f20)

**Test**

```
knayak=# select generate_series(date '2018-01-31',
knayak(#                        date '2018-05-31',
knayak(#                        interval '1 month')::date
knayak-# as frequency;
 frequency
------------
 2018-01-31
 2018-02-28
 2018-03-28
 2018-04-28
 2018-05-28
(5 rows)

Time: 0.303 ms
knayak=#
knayak=#
knayak=# SELECT
knayak-#   (date_trunc('month', dt) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day' ):: DATE AS frequency
knayak-# FROM
knayak-#   generate_series(
knayak(#     DATE '2018-01-31', DATE '2018-05-31',
knayak(#     interval '1 MONTH'
knayak(#   ) AS dt
knayak-# ;
 frequency
------------
 2018-01-31
 2018-02-28
 2018-03-31
 2018-04-30
 2018-05-31
(5 rows)

Time: 0.425 ms
```

Comment: The performance is very good, but I assume OP wants his function to handle any interval, not just 1 month.

Comment: @eurotrash : That may be true. But, this method could be cleverly converted to a generalised function with more or less the same performance ( without OP's while loops, of course!)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
SELECT '2000-01-31'::DATE + ('1 MONTH'::INTERVAL)*x FROM generate_series(0,100) x;
```

**Drawback:**

Since generate_series() parameters are integers, you need to calculate them.

**Massive advantage:**

generate_series() gives correct row count estimates to the optimizer when its parameters are integers, but it isn't smart enough to do so when its parameters are dates and intervals:

This is very important especially if you use it to build a huge series. Using date parameters will always return default 1000 row estimates, which can cause the optimizer to go for a catastrophic plan.

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE foo( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, dt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO foo (dt) SELECT '2000-01-01'::TIMESTAMP + ('1 SECOND'::INTERVAL)*x FROM generate_series(1,1000000) x;
CREATE INDEX foo_dt ON foo(dt);
VACUUM ANALYZE foo;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH d AS (SELECT '2000-01-01'::TIMESTAMP + ('10 SECOND'::INTERVAL)*x dt FROM generate_series(1,100000) x)
SELECT * FROM foo JOIN d USING (dt);
 Hash Join  (cost=27906.00..30656.00 rows=100000 width=12) (actual time=191.020..237.268 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone + ('00:00:10'::interval * (x.x)::double precision)) = foo.dt)
   ->  Function Scan on generate_series x  (cost=0.00..1000.00 rows=100000 width=4) (actual time=7.070..11.096 rows=100000 loops=1)
     CORRECT ESTIMATE -------------------------------------------------^
   ->  Hash  (cost=15406.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=12) (actual time=181.844..181.845 rows=1000000 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 51161kB
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=12) (actual time=0.009..64.702 rows=1000000 loops=1)

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH d AS (SELECT generate_series('2000-01-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2000-01-12 13:46:40'::TIMESTAMP, '10 SECOND'::INTERVAL) dt)
SELECT * FROM foo JOIN d USING (dt);
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..7515.52 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.050..139.251 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.02 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.006..5.493 rows=100001 loops=1)
     WRONG ESTIMATE ----------------------^
         ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using foo_dt on foo  (cost=0.42..7.49 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=100001)
         Index Cond: (dt = (generate_series('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, '2000-01-12 13:46:40'::timestamp without time zone, '00:00:10'::interval)))
```

With the correct estimate, it uses a hash which is the right thing to do here. With the wrong, much too low estimate, it uses a nested loop index scan instead. If the stars align just right, that's one random IO per page.